# Problem while installing Tensorflow on Jupyter notebook in python 3 kernel

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I am building a deep learning project with `tensorflow` using Jupyter Notebook in Python 3 kernel, I want to install `tensorflow`, `gpu`, and the libraries as shown in the photo below. However an error occurred which says:

```
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [44 lines of output]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 35, in __init__
      parsed = parse_requirement(requirement_string)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\_parser.py", line 64, in parse_requirement
      return _parse_requirement(Tokenizer(source, rules=DEFAULT_RULES))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\_parser.py", line 82, in _parse_requirement
      url, specifier, marker = _parse_requirement_details(tokenizer)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\_parser.py", line 126, in _parse_requirement_details
      marker = _parse_requirement_marker(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\_parser.py", line 147, in _parse_requirement_marker
      tokenizer.raise_syntax_error(
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\_tokenizer.py", line 163, in raise_syntax_error
      raise ParserSyntaxError(
  setuptools.extern.packaging._tokenizer.ParserSyntaxError: Expected end or semicolon (after name and no valid version specifier)
      python_version>"3.7"
                ^
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Riona\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bqv5w20a\tensorflow-gpu_12262bc756d34c5dbb8ca6a786902af3\setup.py", line 40, in <module>
      setuptools.setup()
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 106, in setup
      _install_setup_requires(attrs)
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 77, in _install_setup_requires
      dist.parse_config_files(ignore_option_errors=True)
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 910, in parse_config_files
      self._finalize_requires()
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 607, in _finalize_requires
      self._move_install_requirements_markers()
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 647, in _move_install_requirements_markers
      inst_reqs = list(_reqs.parse(spec_inst_reqs))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 37, in __init__
      raise InvalidRequirement(str(e)) from e
  setuptools.extern.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Expected end or semicolon (after name and no valid version specifier)
      python_version>"3.7"
                    ^
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

​

I tried to install those dependencies for my model, but it resulted like this, the photo given below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DW8bh.png)

Comment: Kindly answer my query

Comment: Hi @Magic Math, Could you please try installing tensorflow using the [TF install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native) official link. Please check the Hardware/Software requirements for the GPU setup and install the compatible version of Tensorflow, CUDA and cuDNN to the installed python version as mentioned in the [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu). Please ensure to install Tensorflow <=2.10 for GPU support on native-Windows, starting in TF 2.11, CUDA build is not supported for Windows. Thank you.